# Allow limited keyboard digits in edit text, android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, digits

I want to allow only alphabets, numbers and some of the special characters in Edit text:

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ()*-_,;':."
```

I also want to allow am-percent(&) and double quote (")
When I add am-percent in digits i get this error

```
The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
```

How do I add both of these special characters??

Comment: How about to use a TextWatcher class on your EditText?

Comment: @WiSHY see my answer below hope It will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `&amp;` and `&quot;`

You can find a full list here: 
[List of XML and HTML character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression for achieve this